# How to create helper method HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, devise, haml

I inherited a project that uses Ruby on Rails and HAML and I have never seen HAML before so I'm kind of confused.  This project is using devise to handle users and devise send flash events or something to notify when a user has logged in or user has failed to log in and other events like that.  My problem is that the flash notifications are hard coded to be certain types and I want to tie them to bootstrap alerts with some customization.  I know that I can edit the text of the devise notifications but I can't change their types.  I have a partial file that is included to display the alerts.

```
- if flash[:error]
  .alert.alert-error
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
    = flash[:error].html_safe
- elsif flash[:alert]
  .alert.alert-error
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
    = flash[:alert]
- elsif flash[:notice]
  .alert.alert-warning
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
    = flash[:notice]
- elsif flash[:success]
  .alert.alert-success
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
    = flash[:success]
```

What I would like to do is prefix the devise strings with the alert type that I want them to be.

Take this

```
Successful log in!
```

And turn it into this

```
alert-info|Successful log in!
```

Then parse the alter type and alter the string.  I have no idea if this is possible with a helper method or not.

Answer (score 1):

`= flash[:success]` is the HAML equivelant of ERB's `<%= flash[:success] %>`

Knowing this, you can use normal ruby code to write what you want to show. Additionally, to write simple text in HAML, you just put it on its own line (maintaining proper indention):

```
- if flash[:success]
  .alert.alert-success
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
    My custom text
    = flash[:success]
```

This will translate to:

```
<% if flash[:success] %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">&times;</button>
    My custom text
    <%= flash[:success] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Notice where I placed *"My custom text"* in the two code samples above.

For additional help with understanding the HAML madness, see: [HAML Documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_) and the [Online HAML Conversion Tool](https://haml2erb.org/)

**UPDATE**

If you're wanting to parse the `flash` string and display a div based on the prefix, create a helper like this:

```
# application_helper.rb
def display_flash(input_message)
  if input_message
    # Split the prefix from the actual message
    prefix, output_message = input_message.split('|')

    # Use HAML's haml_tag to create your div, button, etc.
    haml_tag(:div, class: "alert #{prefix}") do
      output_message
    end
  end
end
```

Hopefully this it closer to solving your problem than before. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response but maybe i didnt make myself clear, I'm going to update the resource file for the string that devise uses with "alert-info|" or "alert-success|" prefixed on the strings.  If that prefix exists I was to decide what kind of alert class to put on the div and strip the prefix off and render the string in the div.  I think I need to create some sort of helper method to do this and I also couldn't get nested if statements to work with HAML

Comment: Ok, I understand a little better now. Modifying devise and adding a prefix to the string is almost redundant because the string will be passed through a particular `flash` with the key being the type of alert (`:success`, `:alert`, etc.) The keys used can technically be anything you want, so if you go as far as to edit devise, you could create `flash[:green]` flashes if you wish.

With that being said, I'll update my answer to help you parse the string from devise.